# Is it possible to hyperlink to a file with a partial address?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of job numbers for work in column B in a worksheet in Excel2010, I want to be able to click each value and have it open up the corresponding folder on our server (whioch contains all kinds of files for the job). The problem is that the folders are created by humans and are human readable.

For example, column B may contain Job "J9600" and each subsequent column contains other information, but on the server the folder is called "J9600 - Mr Smith - jobtitlehere" and this foldername is typed by hand (so prone to deviation from standards, and errors, and just bad spelling).

Is there anyway to say "open a folder, in this location, that begins with J9600"

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of, at least not directly. As it is Excel you could try to write a macro for it that lists the server directory for entries with the name `J9600*` and if there is only one match open it using the explorer or open any of the folders that matched.

For a way to open a folder you could take this answer: [How to open a folder in Windows Explorer from VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205719/how-to-open-a-folder-in-windows-explorer-from-vba)

For a solution to search that folder look at [this](http://software-solutions-online.com/list-files-and-folders-in-a-directory/).

Now your column with the Project name would have to call a function which takes its content as a Parameter and look for that in the project directory.

Using the above sources you might end up with a procedure that might look like the following that you'd call by giving it the JobID in which case it would start to look for `JobID*` in the server directory.

```
Sub openServerDirectory(needle As String)
    Dim varDirectory As Variant
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strDirectory As String

    strDirectory = "\\server\directory"
    i = 1
    flag = True
    varDirectory = Dir(strDirectory, vbDirectory)
    needle = needle & "*"

    While flag = True
        If varDirectory = "" Then
            flag = False
        Else
            If varDirectory Like (needle) Then
                Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & (strDirectory & varDirectory) & "", vbNormalFocus
            End If

            'returns the next file or directory in the path
            varDirectory = Dir
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: The simplest solution would be to remove user readable names and have all folders named by job number only - then have everyone use the excel doc to find folders (a better solution would be access, but even getting people at work to use spreadsheets is difficult enough)...

Comment: So what should I make of your comment? That this is too complicated? In that case you're probably out of luck if you don't manage to change the process. As you already noted: Having a fixed format would be the easiest.

Comment: Hi, no not too complicated, it would work well, I was adding fluff to the conversation about how I wouldnt need to do these things if the company had a proper system

Comment: AH OK. If you do take this as your solution don't forget to mark it. Even if it would be nice if someone comes around with a better one. :D